# Error when working with AngularFireList, data retrieval

Tags: database, angular, firebase, ionic3, data-retrieval

I have succeeded in following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtKjv92L0ihAJ90_NbqCINRu4uKy3RJJU) to log data to my Firebase database. However while following this tutorial I realized he uses "FirebaseListObservable" which is now updated to "AngularFireList". I changed this, and in order to get this to work I had to ensure that I kept my transaction as an object as opposed to an array which he has done.

My code: `transactionRef$: AngularFireList<transaction>`

His code: `shoppingItemRef$: FirebaseListObservable<ShoppingItem[]>`

As I said, this fixed my error here and my data was logged correctly to the database. However, when continuing through the tutorials and trying to achieve data retrieval, I quickly received this error:

Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

HTML

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let transaction of transactionRef$ | async">
            <h2>Currency: {{transaction.transactionCurrency}}</h2>
            <h3>Amount: {{transaction.transactionAmount}}</h3>
            <h4>Receiver: {{transaction.transactionReceiver}}</h4>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database'; 
import { transaction } from '../../models/transaction/transaction.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-view',
  templateUrl: 'view.html',
})
export class ViewPage {

  transactionRef$: AngularFireList<transaction>

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams: NavParams, private database: AngularFireDatabase) {

    this.transactionRef$ = this.database.list('transaction');
  }
}
```

To fix this I changed this line: `<ion-item *ngFor="let transaction of transactionRef$ | async">`

To: `<ion-item *ngFor="let transaction of transactionRef$">`

However, this gave me the following error:

Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Upon reading these two errors, it is clear that the fault is because of the incompatible types object and array. However, I do not know how to fix this. I have read multiple posts with people having these two errors, but most are either working with JSON (I am not), or are using "FirebaseListObservable" and therefore can fix their error by either changing it from an object to an array or leaving out the "| aysnc", neither of which work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `Observable<Response>` from `AngularFireList` from 5.x onwards, use `valueChanges()` function.

```
this.transactionRef$ = this.database.list('transaction').valueChanges();
```

Refer - https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#50

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I'm pretty new to working with angular. 

Am i missing something? like an import statement or?
I have edited my code like you said but get this error:

Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList,transaction>'.
Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}[]>'.
(property) ViewPage.transactionRef$: AngularFireList<transaction>

Comment: Did you try with or without `async` ?